# Run coroutine loop in different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I want to call `streamSimulation` four times split among 2 threads.

How can I create a second loop, create a second thread and execute the loop in that thread?

```
import asyncio
import functools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


async def streamSimulation(p1,p2,p3,p4):
    print("Stream init")
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("Stream Simulation")
        print("Params: " + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4)
        doSomething()

def doSomething():
    print("Did something")

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #Supposed to run in first thread
    asyncio.ensure_future(streamSimulation("P1","P2","P3","P4"))
    asyncio.ensure_future(streamSimulation("A1","A2","A3","A4"))
    #Supposed to run in second thread
    asyncio.ensure_future(streamSimulation("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"))
    asyncio.ensure_future(streamSimulation("B1","B2","B3","B4"))
    loop.run_forever()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea conflicts with asynchronous way, sorry.

In general you need a *single event loop* in *main* thread and *thread pool* for executing *CPU bound* tasks.

The reason for the *single loop* is: it is *IO-bound*, the code executed by loop should never block *except waiting for IO/timer events*.

It means two loops will not give performance boost: they are both blocked by kernel IO subsystem.

The only exception is making work two different event loops together, e.g. asyncio and Qt (but for this particular case there is [qualmash](https://github.com/harvimt/quamash) project).

Comment: Im trying to listen to several websockets and write something to a DB. Would this be IO?

Comment: Why you cannot listen several websockets in the same event loop? [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) allows to do it BTW.
asyncio has no restrictions for supported TCP ports amount.

Comment: Performance reasons. I have to listen to a ton of high traffic websockets at the same time, aggregate some values and send them to the DB. I just realized, that multithreading won't increase performance due to GIL. Looking into multiprocessing now, seems like a `ProcessPoolExecutor`might be the way to go. But it doesn't seem possible to execute a coroutine with `run_in_executor`. Currently using the websockets package.

Comment: Your initial question has neither `ProcessPoolExecutor` nor `run_in_executor` words. I don't see your problem and cannot help.